# Django TemporaryUploadedFile does not exist but nevertheless it is read successfully

Tags: python, linux, django, file-upload, temporary-files

I have the following situation here. My OS shows that django `TemporaryUploadedFile` which I got via the POST request does not exist anymore but somehow this uploaded file can be read.
Here is the code

```
text_file = request.FILES['text_file']

print(text_file.temporary_file_path())
os.system('ls -l ' + text_file.temporary_file_path())

fs = FileSystemStorage()
file_new =fs.save(text_file.name, text_file)

print(text_file.temporary_file_path())
os.system('ls -l ' + text_file.temporary_file_path())

fs.delete(file_new)

for chunk in text_file.chunks():
    text += chunk.decode(encoding)

print('Got text OK.')
```

This gives the following output:

```
/tmp/tmp0tngal9t.upload foo.txt
-rw------- 1 mine machine 3072889 oct 18 19:29 /tmp/tmp0tngal9t.upload

/tmp/tmp0tngal9t.upload foo.txt
ls: cannot access '/tmp/tmp0tngal9t.upload': No such file or directory

Got text OK.
```

So `TemporaryUploadedFile` is disappeared after it was saved to `file_new` which later is also deleted. Anyway `text_file` is successfully read by chunks and I get all the text from uploaded `foo.txt` file. How it is possible? From where `text_file.chunks()` gets the data if `text_file` does not exist anymore?

I use:

- `python 3.5.2`
- `django 1.10.2`
- `ubuntu 16.04.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this problem still remains for bare python, so it is not particularly related to django as in this example I just read `text_file` which were open in `request.FILES['text_file']`.

I re-asked the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40148622/how-python-reads-a-file-when-it-was-deleted-after-being-open) focusing on python only. It turned out that the problem is not so related with python either, but with Linux/Unix system file management. I quote here the [answer of Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40148622/how-python-reads-a-file-when-it-was-deleted-after-being-open/40148668#40148668):

> Nothing to do with Python. In C, Fortran, or Visual Cobol you'd have
>   the same behaviour as long as the code gets its handle from open
>   system call.
>
> On Linux/Unix systems, once a process has a handle on a file, it can
>   read it, even if the file is deleted. For more details check that
>   question (I wasn't sure if it was OK to do that, it seems to be)
>
> On Windows you just wouldn't be able to delete the file as long as
>   it's locked by a process.